# Laravel Eloquent not returning all related models

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a model that is not returning related models, Call and CallType are my models, with a One-to-One relationship.

Call Model

```
public function calltype(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\CallType');
}
```

CallType Model

```
public function call(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Call');
}
```

CallsController index method

```
 $calls = Call::all();
    $user_group = Group::find(Auth::user()->group_id);

    return view('settings.calls.index', compact('calls', 'user_group'));
```

calls.blade.php

```
@foreach($calls as $call)

   <tr>
     <td>{{$call->call_code}}</td>
     <td>{{$call->call_name}}</td>
     <td>{{$call->calltype->type}}</td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

Calls Migration

```
Schema::create('calls', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('call_type_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('call_name');
            $table->string('call_code');
            $table->date('start_date');
            $table->date('end_date');
            $table->string('target_audience')->nullable();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();

            $table->foreign('call_type_id')->references('id')->on('call_types');
        });
```

CallTypes Migration

```
 Schema::create('call_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
        //
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('type');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I am getting this error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

and when I do `dd($calls)` it has no related models. What am I doing wrong? please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
in blade

```
 @if(isset($calls))
   @foreach($calls as $call)
    <tr>
     <td>{{$call->call_code}}</td>
     <td>{{$call->call_name}}</td>
     <td>{{$call->calltype->type}}</td>
   </tr>
   @endforeach
@endif
```

Make sure that index is `calls` not `$calls`

in clontroller

```
return view('calls')->with(['calls'=>$calls,'user_group'=> $user_group]);
```

Comment: But still, even if I do that, `calltype` is null.. `calltype` is supposed to be returned when i do `$call = Call::all();` but it's not being returned.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use eager loading to minimize db queries.

Change:

```
$calls = Call::all();
```

into

```
$calls = Call::with('calltype')->get();
```

The error you get is because probably you don't have calltype set for each call, so you should change in your template:

```
<td>{{$call->calltype->type}}</td>
```

into

```
<td>{{ $call->calltype ? $call->calltype->type : '-' }}</td>
```

Comment: I only have one call, and it has a type. Thanks for the eager loading suggestion. or maybe it's the way I defined my relationships. I have edited the original post to depict the migrations

Comment: And i must say this worked before. or in the case where I have more than one call all with types, it only returns one type, and fails for the rest. It's really behaving strangely.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was supposed to have a hasMany on the CallType, because each CallType can have many Calls assigned to it. it should be like this:

CallType Model

```
public function calls()
{
 return $this->hasMany('App\Call');
}
```

Call model

```
public function call_type(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\CallType');
}
```